# HTTP requisitions GET

Tags: get, xmlhttprequest

When I go to the developer tools of the browser, and click a button on a site, I receve a get requisitions. If do this get with the link that appears in the developer tolls, its the same that i "click" on the button?

[GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JAzc.png)

My code:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
const url = 'https://www.meuspremiosnick.com.br/vote/tiktoker-do-ano'
var j=0;
function votar()
{
    http.open('GET',url,false);

http.send('https://sviakcanickglobal.112.2o7.net/b/ss/viakcanickglobal,vianickelodeonintl/1/JS-2.2.0/s5711041450902?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=31/7/2020 14:33:26 1 180&mid=91423556843279868591240211340791917389&aamlh=4&ce=UTF-8&pageName=kca-br|events|voting&g=https://www.meuspremiosnick.com.br/vote/&c.=&v.=&activity=actioncall&appName=kca Ubuntu&brandID=kca-br&pageFranchise=kca2020&pageURL=https://www.meuspremiosnick.com.br&pageType=voting-page&actName=clicks on vote_TikToker do Ano_Doarda&destination=no destination&modname=voting_items&bentoVersion=2.0.0&.v=&.c=&aamb=6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y&pe=lnk_o&pev2=https://www.meuspremiosnick.com.br/vote/tiktoker-do-ano&s=1680x1050&c=24&j=1.6&v=N&k=Y&bw=807&bh=919&mcorgid=ED7001AC512D2ABD0A490D4C@AdobeOrg&AQE=1');

http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
        j=j+1;
        console.log(http.responseText);
        console.log('Votos: '+j);
        
    }
}

}

setInterval(votar,200);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i have seen it depends on the site and usually it's not the case. For example this site i was automating today had a next page button. When that button is clicked next 100 data rows are loaded. On click a POST request is made which returns the data rows in response. Now when i made the same request in the console nothing changed but i did see the response data in console. The reason being on the front end when that next page button is clicked POST request is made by some function. That function then waits for the response and on successful response it loads the rows. Now when i make the request myself no function is waiting for the response so the data won't load.

In short the request is usually not what triggers the related functionality. Usually it's just a middle man to fetch data while the original triggered function waits.

Comment: If I use proxy like Charles Porxy I can see detailed information about what happens when i click the button and do the same in a script?

Comment: A little background would be better. But if you wanna imitate it's functionality in a script then using it's API directly is the way to go (that is if functionality of that button is to save or retrieve some content from back end ).